# Submodule's files are not checked out

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to add an external repo as a submodule of my repo, so I followed [these instructions](http://www.undefinedrange.com/posts/git-submodules-external-repositories-and-deployment), doing:

```
git submodule add git:... vendor
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

then I tired:

```
git submodule init vendor
git submodule update vendor
```

The submodule that I'm adding has submodules, and the submodule's submodules appear to to be checkedout (ie: I see the files on my hard drive) but the files for the submodule itself are not checkout out.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is [the repo that I'm trying to add as a submodule](http://github.com/jbalogh/zamboni-lib), and it's `src` directory is all that I see in my checkout/clone, along with the sub directories and files or `src`, but I don't have the readme file for example.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since git version 1.6.5 you can use the `--recursive` and `--init` options to `git submodule update` to make sure that submodules are recursively initialized and updated.  So, for your example, the following works for me:

```
$ git submodule add git://github.com/jbalogh/zamboni-lib.git vendor
remote: Counting objects: 7001, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5985/5985), done.
remote: Total 7001 (delta 1137), reused 6337 (delta 736)
Receiving objects: 100% (7001/7001), 14.88 MiB | 1.99 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1137/1137), done.
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
[... lots of output ...]
```

I hope that's of some use.

Comment: Excellent! I had forgotten about this question, and about the `git update` options. +1